# Get all set css Properties of an element via Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently workin on a HTML Designer (https://github.com/node-projects/web-component-designer). For this in need to read all set css properties of an object.
At the moment I use this code:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  let node = document.querySelector('b-c');
  for (let s of node.style) {
    let val = node.style[s];
    console.log(s, val)
    //if (val && typeof val === 'string')
      //designItem.styles.set(s, node.style[s]);
  }
}
```

```html
<b-c style="background: var(--kx-dark)"></b-c>
```

The problem is, with the for loop I do not get all styles. For example, you don't get the "background" in the loop

Comment: can't understand your issue. Do you want to read some tag's CSS and then apply it to others or do you have a JSON object?

Comment: Are you looking for the definition or the computed style?

Comment: The issue is that browsers do not return bundled style properties using the collection like the OP does.

Answer (score 1):

To get `--kx-dark` you can read the attribute of the tag

Also the var is visible when getting the `background` which is a grouped style not showing as .style[..]

Note the loop does not resolve the computedStyle so no background-color either from the loop - here are a few workarounds

```js
document.querySelectorAll("b-c").forEach((elem, i) => console.log(i, elem.getAttribute("style")))


//getComputedStyle does not show --kx-dark

document.querySelectorAll("b-c").forEach((elem, i) => console.log(i, window.getComputedStyle(elem).backgroundColor))

// let's try this:

window.onload = function() {
  const styleDict = {}
  let nodes = document.querySelectorAll('b-c');
  nodes.forEach((node,i) => {
    for (let s of node.style) {
      styleDict[s] = node.style[s];
      if (s.indexOf("-") != -1) { // get the bundle
        const mainStyle = s.split("-")[0]
        styleDict[mainStyle] = node.style[mainStyle];
      }
    }
    console.log(i,styleDict)
  })
}
```

```css
:root {
  --kx-dark: rgb(165, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<b-c style="background: var(--kx-dark)">Is this brown?</b-c>

<b-c style="background-color: var(--kx-dark)">Is this brown?</b-c>
```

Comment: `Object.entries(node.style).filter((item) => isNaN(item[0]) && item[1])`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't see the background style is because there is no such thing as a background style. To be more clear, while there is a background style, it's actually a collection of other styles.
What you see in a browser's developers tool is actually a shorthand of several background styles that are chained in the single `background` that are later parsed into their specific attributes.

Look at your code

```js
let node = document.querySelector('b-c');
for (let s of node.style) {
    let val = node.style[s];
    console.log(s, val)
}
```

```html
<b-c style="background: var(--kx-dark);color:red;"></b-c>
```

You can see the `color` style as well as all the properties extracted from the background value.

Now look at this code

```js
let node = document.querySelector('b-c');
  for (let s of node.style) {
    let val = node.style[s];
    console.log(s, val)
}
```

```html
<b-c style="background-color: var(--kx-dark);color:red;"></b-c>
```

You get only two values, because there is only one specific background value.

Comment: Curiously the `background` property is part of the collection according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference).

Comment: It is, but its content is used to populate the appropriate styles attributes, as you can see in the first example in my answer. So on the - let's call it the element's base style - only the translated styles are considered. That's also why you don't see the value in the parsed styles, because the value isn't recognized as one of the accepted values.

Comment: @Lain [The MDN link provided by you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference) also says [background is a shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background), as well as it explains [what shorthand properties are](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties)

Comment: @Nakarukatoshi Uzumaki still as lain wrote, shorthand properties are part of the collection. can check it yourself `Object.entries(node.style)`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let elem = document.querySelector("#title");

function getAllStyleProperties(elem){
    let allStyle = {};
    if(elem){
        let styleText = elem.style.cssText;
        let allStyleText = styleText.split(";");
        allStyleText.forEach((style) => {
            if(style){
                let [properties, value] = style.split(":");
                allStyle[properties.trim()] = value.trim();
            }
        })
    }
    return allStyle;
}

console.log(getAllStyleProperties(elem))
```

```html
<h1 style="background: var(--kx-dark); margin: 10px" id="title">Hello World</h1>
```

You can try this...

Answer (score 0):

You maybe able to get it done with `window.getComputedStyle()`

`getComputedStyle()` return all css properties of including browsers default css properties

read more information about **[Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)**

###### Sample usage of `window.getComputedStyle()` related to your case

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let node = document.querySelector('b-c');
  const cssStyles = getComputedStyle(node);
  for (const cssProperty in cssStyles) {
    const cssValue = cssStyles.getPropertyValue(cssProperty);
    // This is not just limited to inline styles but also to all other css properties
    if (cssProperty === "background") {
      console.log({
        [cssProperty]: cssValue
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
   :root {
    --kx-dark: red;
  }
</style>

<b-c style="background: var(--kx-dark)">B-C</b-c>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use the `getComputedStyle` function to fetch all styles applied to element.

```
function dumpCSSText(element){
    var s = '';
    var o = getComputedStyle(element);
    for(var i = 0; i < o.length; i++){
        s+=o[i] + ':' + o.getPropertyValue(o[i])+';';
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Try it. It is not there